# Checking login user AuthorizePolicy in Razor page on Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity-3

I'm looking for a variant of this

```
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User) && User.IsInRole(Roles.Administrator))
{
    <div id="editArticle">
```

but instead of checking after the role I'm after a check into the policy much like you would in a controller by doing this.

```
[Authorize(Policy = Policies.RequireAdmin)]
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This seems similar to question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36068655/any-way-to-use-authorization-policies-in-a-view-in-net-core-1-0-mvc)

> I found this link which may be helpful: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/views.html

Examples from that page:

```
@if (await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "PolicyName"))
{
    <p>This paragraph is displayed because you fulfilled PolicyName.</p>
}
```

> In some cases the resource will be your view model, and you can call
>   AuthorizeAsync in exactly the same way as you would check during
>   resource based authorization;

```
@if (await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, Model, Operations.Edit))
{
    <p><a class="btn btn-default" role="button"
    href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Document", new {id= Model.Id})">Edit</a></p>
}
```

Comment: This is just great. :D For the next one looking for this you need `@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization` and `@inject IAuthorizationService AuthorizationService` aswell

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for putting the using... clause into this answer, MS forgot that important bit of info in their docs.

Comment: @JReam hehe yea i just wished that people would upvote the question instead of the comment :P

Comment: In all these anwsers only the @Talnaci Sergiu Vlad´s anwser works.

Answer (score 23):

With Dot net core 2.0 AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync no longer returns a boolean, it returns a AuthorizationResult. A working version for dot net core 2.0 will be something like this:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@inject IAuthorizationService AuthorizationService

@if ((await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "RequireAuthenticatedUser")).Succeeded)
{
     <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Roles" asp-action="Index">Roles</a></li>
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Therefore the complete view contains:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@inject IAuthorizationService AuthorizationService

// Your HTML elements and i.e.:
@if (await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "RequireAuthenticatedUser"))
{
     <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Roles" asp-action="Index">Roles</a></li>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To put it even more succinctly:

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.IAuthorizationService authorizationService

@if (await authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, null, "RequireAuthenticatedUser"))
{
     <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Roles" asp-action="Index">Roles</a></li>
}
```

It appears `AuthorizeAsync()` requires the resource parameter, but null can be passed as in my example.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use this in many views, then you'd better implement a custom *RazorPage*:

```
public abstract class MyRazorPage<T> : RazorPage<T>
{
    public async Task<bool> HasPolicyAsync(string policyName)
    {
        var authorizationService = Context.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IAuthorizationService)) as IAuthorizationService;
        bool isAdmin = (await authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, policyName)).Succeeded;
        return isAdmin;
    }
}
```

then open *_ViewImports.cshtml* and add the next instruction:

```
@inherits MyRazorPage<TModel>
```

now you can call *HasPolicyAsync()* method from any view:

```
    if (await HasPolicyAsync(Policies.RequireAdmin))
    {
        <h2>Admin is authorized</h2>
    }
```

It would look much more concise.

Answer (score 1):

Its best handled with TagHelpers in most scenarios now.
You can use it like:

```
<li policy="@MyGroups.Administrators">
....
```

So no longer Magicstrings :-)

See: https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2017/11/05/authorize-tag-helper.aspx

Comment: This requires TagHelperSamples.Authorization nuget package, if I'm not mistaken.